# Chaining two actions in ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have two related actions that should be triggered one after another.

I would like to do this with `@effects` or `reducers`

in my slider.component I trigger the first parent action

```
valueChange(event: MatSliderChange) {
  this.store.dispatch(
    new SetSelectDateTime({ dateSelect: this.date, timeSelect: event.source.displayValue })
  );
}
```

Then in reducer

```
case ESelectDateTimeActionTypes.SetSelectDateTime: {

  return {
    ...state,
    dateTimeSelect: action.payload
  };
}
```

Now I should trigger the second actions to get new data dependings on selected time
So I created an effect `updateActualTrips`

```
export class SchedulingsEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private apiCallsService: ApiCallsService
  ) {}
  loadSchedulings$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.apiCallsService.getSchedulings().pipe(
          map(trips => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess, payload: trips })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );

  $LoadKpiMission = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<any>(EKpiActions.GetMissionsByStation),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.apiCallsService.getKpiMissionByStation(action.payload, '2016-04-18').pipe(
          map(trips => ({ type: EKpiActions.GetMissionsByStationSuccess, payload: trips })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );
  $updateActualTrips = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<any>(ESelectDateTimeActionTypes.SetSelectDateTime),
      map(action => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetNextSchedulesByTime, payload: action.payload }))
    )
  );
}
```

The problem is that the effect is never triggered but the selected time is updated

**Update**
I noticed that the effect is triggered  the first time when `SetSelectDateTime` is getting initialized

Comment: Is your effects class registered in the `EffectsModule`? See [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects)

Comment: yes other effects inside the class are working, I have updated my question with all the effect class

Comment: So what is the problem here? Your valueChange not being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, there is no effect waiting for the action `ESchedulesActions.GetNextSchedulesByTime`, the only other actions you are waiting for are `ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate` and `EKpiActions.GetMissionsByStation`.

Are you missing an actual effect here or do we not see the complete code? Nothing in your code would ask the API for new data when `SetSelectDateTime` is dispatched.

Or are you saying that `ESchedulesActions.GetNextSchedulesByTime` is never dispatched to the store in the first place (when the effect listening for `SetSelectDateTime` is run)?